# How do I change rx.Observable<java.util.list<T>> to java.util.list<T>

Tags: java, android

Declaration

```
@GET("api/Game/SearchGames")
Observable<List<GameModel>> searchGames();
```

This is the network call

```
public static Observable<List<GameModel>> searchGames () {
    VersusAPI client = VersusServiceGenerator.createService(VersusAPI.class);
    Observable<List<GameModel>> ob = client.searchGames();
    return ob;
}
```

Here is where I implement.

```
mAdapterMyGames = new RecyclerViewAdapter(searchGames());
```

`searchGames()` returns `rx.Observable<java.util.list<GameModel>>`. How do I change that to  only `java.util.list<GameModel>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't properly understand what is an `Observable`.
It is an object, to which You can `subscribe()` to get the result of it's operation. Usually, only when subscribing to an `Observable` it starts and you can get the result inside `Subscriber`'s `onNext()` function.
So in your case:

1. Subscribe to this `Observable`.
2. Look for the result inside this subscriber's `onNext` function.

   ```
   searchGames().subscribe(new new Subscriber<List<GameModel>>() {
       @Override
       public void onNext(List<GameModel> gameModels) {
            //TODO make sth useful with models
       }

       @Override
       public void onCompleted() { }

       @Override
       public void onError(Throwable e) { }
   )
   ```